# Can't use Noto Color Emoji with Conky

Tags: conky

I have a config file with this text

```
...
# Weather
${color orange}Weather ${hr 2}$color
${execpi 3600 ~/.conky/Chau/weather.lua}]];
```

[Here is the weather.lua](https://pastebin.com/Tkj7Y9Ss)

The output contains an emoji and it is displayed correctly in [text editor](https://prnt.sc/oh93jq) as well as [terminal](https://prnt.sc/oh93q5), [fc-match detected the font too](https://prnt.sc/oh9a9c). However, when I pass it to conky the first day, it display the emoji using DejaVu Sans font (sadly, no screenshot). The next day (and until now) it turns worse: [only a rectangle is displayed](https://prnt.sc/oh97qk).

*Update: Well, I've just found out that it changes into rectangle because the weather changes. DejaVu only have two emoji corresponding to sunny and cloudy.*

I notice a strange behavior: if I write Noto Color Emoji without "" conky will crash, but with "" the emoji will be incorrectly displayed as I described above. I've successfully set the font to Source Code Pro without "" and conky works fine but with Noto Color Emoji it crashes, don't have a clue.

How to force conky to use Noto Color Emoji to display my emoji? Thanks.

Edit: This is what conky prints when it crashes:

```
conky: desktop window (1a7) is root window
conky: window type - override
conky: drawing to created window (0x5400001)
conky: drawing to double buffer
conky: forked to background, pid is 17944
conky: X Error: type 0 Display 55ede23215f0 XID 88080392 serial 558 
error_code 16 request_code 139 minor_code 20 other Display: 55ede23215f0
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in *cairo*, the graphics library behind conky. See for example [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/issues/326). There seem to be several bits of software that have not managed to handle colour emojis, so it might be quite a wait until there are no problems in various releases.

Comment: Thank you for that information :D